# Test Target to debug as root process

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging

I have added a new test target in xcode. I want to test my unit test cases by running it as root since it involves creation of certain directories where root has permissions. But I find that it is disabled to select the process to run as root.Any help on how to test it with root permissions ?
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem ! Even if the main target is set to launch as root, it is still disabled !

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and managed to fix it by manually editing the corresponding *.xcscheme file.

Assuming you have the "Run" configuration set up to do this, you will see the following in the `*.xcscheme` file:

```
  <LaunchAction
  ...
  debugAsWhichUser = "root"
  ...>
      ...
  </LaunchAction>
```

Simply add the property manually to the `TestAction` section as well:

```
  <TestAction
  ...
  debugAsWhichUser = "root"
  ...>
      ...
  </TestAction>
```

After making this change, I simply restarted XCode, and now the disabled radio buttons show the correct value as seen here:
[Correct settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gydyD.png)

Running verified for me that it all worked!
* I should mention that this was on Version 8.1 (8B62), I have no reason to think this should vary by version but YMMV.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me - xcodebuild freezes if I try to execute test action with root permissions. That happens even with test suite, that contains one empty test.

Comment: @TimMyers,  Hi, I just wonder if theres any way to insert this configuration to common project scheme (not per user). I'm working on a project and I've developed new Test scheme that should run always as root . I wish to add this configuration once, and not per user. thanks !